# Add a <servlet> into web.xml in Grails 2.1

Tags: grails, web.xml, grails-plugin, grails-2.1

I want to add a  node into web.xml.
I tried to use a webxml grails plugin, but look like it can't manage  nodes. Any help or example will be apreciated...

Comment: what do you mean with '*node*'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your own `web.xml`, with any content you want. Run

```
> grails install-templates
```

and edit `/src/templates/war/web.xml` file (it's a template, so don't remove existing Grails code)

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html

Comment: Thanks Igor! I followed your advice, but got the following error: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.1.1:install-templates (default-cli) on project web_portal: Unable to start Grails: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: User input is not enabled, cannot obtain input stream -> [Help 1]
Couldn't you please advise?

Comment: I finally kind of resolved that. I used mvn grails:install-templates command. Looks like it doesn't work from maven for some reason. I installed Grails, issues the command and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to add comments yet, so here it goes.

By looking at your last comment, I suppose that you were looking for *grails:exec*:

```
mvn grails:exec -Dcommand=install-templates
```

Many Grails commands don't have the equivalent wrapper exposed directly through Maven.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware about this kind of command. I'll try that as well.